# Clinically meaningful explanation of marginal treatment effect (MTE) in instrument variable study

Tags: econometrics, causality, instrumental-variables, treatment-effect

I am working on an instrumental variable application using clinical data. We will use a so-called preference-based instrument. We may include this as a continuous variable. With a continous instrument, we can obtain the average marginal treatment effect (AMTE). I am having some trouble translating this from the standard econometrics jargon to a clinically relevant formulation that clinicians may find meaningful and intuitive.

I've seen several formulations, but they all rely on understanding the specific use of "marginal" in this context. I have studied economics, and I'm used to thinking of the marginal effect as the change in outcome given a one unit change in the independent variable. (In statistics, I know it can refer to the unconditional mean.) However, in the context of AMTE with a continuous instrument, categorical treatment and outcome, I am unsure how it can be described in more layman terms. I've seen several formulations, e.g.

1. "This is the effect of a treatment on the marginal individual
   entering treatment" ([Meghir, 2009](http://www.eief.it/files/2009/12/lecture5.pdf))
2. MTE is "...the difference between the treated potential outcome and the untreated potential outcome for an individual marginal to selecting into treatment ... " ([Kowalski, 2016](http://www.econ.yale.edu/%7Eak669/mte.latest.draft.pdf))
3. "MTE is therefore defined as a continuum of treatment effects along the full distribution of $U_{D}$ (the individual unobserved characteristic that drives treatment decisions)." ([Cornelissen et al., 2016](http://ftp.iza.org/dp10056.pdf))
4. By this description, local IV curves seem to be related or synonymous: "local IV (LIV) curves, i.e. effects among units who would comply right at a given threshold value of the instrument." ([Kennedy et al. 2018](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/rssb.12300))

I'll add that there is at least one more seemingly related [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182761/the-difference-between-average-and-marginal-treatment-effect) that goes into average and marginal treatment effect. I think Meghir's formulation could be what I'm after, but it hinges on understanding "the marginal individual".